# selected data from the database is not showing into dropdown list using angularjs and php

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here I'm tring to get data from database and show it in dropdown list and when selecting it will be stored in database, i'm using angularjs and php but unfortunatly m not getting anything in dropdown list... please help me out.. Thanks in advance..

**This is my html code.**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="bookInfo.site1" placeholder="sites">
            <option ng-repeat="site in bookInfo.site1" value="{{site.Sites}}">{{site.Sites}}</option>
        </select>
<select class="form-control" ng-model="bookInfo.site2" placeholder="sites">
            <option ng-repeat="site in bookInfo.site2" value="{{site.Sites}}">{{site.Sites}}</option>
        </select>
```

**This is my service**

```
app.factory('SiteService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    return {
        getSite1: function(){
            return $http.get('endpoints/selectsite.php').then(function(result) {
                return result.data;
            });
        },
        getSite2: function(animal){
            return $http.get('endpoints/selectsite.php').then(function(result){
                return result.data;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**This is my controller**

```
$scope.bookInfo = {

    sites1: [],
    sites2: []
}

//functions

SiteService.getSite1().then(function(data){
    $scope.bookInfo.sites1 = data;
});

SiteService.getSite2().then(function(data){
    $scope.bookInfo.sites2 = data;
});

$scope.bookVisit = function(){

var data = {

    site1: $scope.bookInfo.site1,
    site2: $scope.bookInfo.site2
}
$http.post("endpoints/book.php", data).success(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    $state.go("application");
}).error(function(error){
    console.error(error);
});
}
```

**This is my php code**

```
<?php
    include("../connection.php");

    $query = "SELECT Sites FROM sitemaster";

    $rs = $db->query($query);

    while($row = $rs->fetchAll()){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    print json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Nothing will return from your factory. use promises. i see you have included `$q` why don't you use it?

Comment: could you please explain it in detail .. actually m new to angular js so m not getting what is happening..

Answer (score 0):

Change your factory to look like this:

```
app.factory('SiteService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    return {
        getSite1: function(){
            var do = $q.defer();
            $http.get('endpoints/selectsite.php').then(function(){
                do.resolve;
            },
            function(){
                do.reject;
            });
            return do.promise;
        },
        getSite2: function(animal){
            var do = $q.defer();
            $http.get('endpoints/selectsite.php').then(function(){
                do.resolve;
            },
            function(){
                do.reject;
            });
            return do.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

I believe this should solve your problem. 
also, remove the `$http.post` from your controller, if you have a factory, put all the api/ajax related code there, like you have done with the `get` requests.

Comment: html seems to be ok.

Comment: and how to call promises in controller for accessing them?

Comment: it is throwing an error...SyntaxError: missing formal parameterbookController.js:18:38
SyntaxError: missing variable name

Comment: paste the complete controller code on here or a jsfiddle. you don't need to call promises, they're resolved when the ajax request is completed and you can access the data in your controller. your code to access the data coming from factory is fine already.

Comment: in your factory `getSite2: function(animal){` you're passing a variable here. where is the variable in your controller? `SiteService.getSite2().then(function(data){`?

Comment: yup.. SyntaxError: missing variable nameauthenticate-service.js:23:16

Comment: so the error is in a different file now? can you check if you're making the same mistake in that file too? seems you need to learn Angular a bit more first.

Comment: I've updated your **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t0sne2n/6/)**. check how to use properties in `select`.

Comment: yeah now everything is rignt sir... but again i cant see anything in dropdown list